# K-Fold Cross Validation for NNs

Tags: neural-network, cross-validation

When using K-Fold CV, is it still useful to have a Train/Validation/Test split?

Or simply just a Train/Test? I.e. split up data into k bins, and leave one out for testing, train on the rest, and take average of the scores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  If you're evaluating your model's performance without tuning hyperparameters, then a train/test split is sufficient.

If you're tuning hyperparameters, then you need a validation set.  Within each fold, you'll train on the training set (of course), using the validation set to tune hyperparameters.  Then you'll evaluate performance on the test set.

Comment: So if using a validation set, and we split the data into 5 groups, there would be 3 for training, 1 for validation, and 1 for testing?

Comment: That's one way to do it.  You can also think of it as having 4 pieces for training+validation, and 1 piece for testing.  Then you can split the training+validation set (the 4 pieces), in whichever way seems appropriate.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yep, perfectly clear. What seemed like such a simple question, was hard to find in all the literature I have been reading. Thanks for your response and understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Very open ended and context dependent, but generally:

You are already have a test set, and actually a "new" one in every CV-fold.

Do your model experimentations with CV, when you are done train on the whole dataset at once.